# What are the strategies to convert an HOCR output to a string (for regex purposes)?

Tags: python, python-tesseract, hocr

I am working with Pytesseract and would like to convert an HOCR output to a string. Of course, such a function is implemented into Pytesseract but I would like to know more about the possible strategies to get it done thx

```py
from pytesseract import image_to_pdf_or_hocr
hocr_output = image_to_pdf_or_hocr(image, extension='hocr')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [hOCR](http://kba.cloud/hocr-spec/1.2/) is a type of .xml we can use a .xml parser.

But first we need to convert the binary output of tesseract to str:

```
from pytesseract import image_to_pdf_or_hocr

hocr_output = image_to_pdf_or_hocr(image, extension='hocr')
hocr = hocr_output.decode('utf-8')
```

Now we can use [xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(hocr)
```

xml.etree provides us with a [text iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext) whose result we can join in a single string:

```
text = ''.join(root.itertext())
```